# Multiplicative homomorphism of Euclidean domains: Do irreducibles never map to reducibles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Suppose I have a multiplicative homomorphism $\phi: R \to S$ between two euclidean domains. Is it true that an irreducible element of $R$ never maps to a reducible element of $S$?

Edit, after first answer: Under what conditions is it true?

Edit:
I would like to refine the question.

Clearly $a \mid b \implies \phi(a) \mid \phi(b)$ for $a,b \in R$. When does the converse hold?

Comment: May I ask what is meant by a _multiplicative_ homomorphism?

Comment: I wanted to emphasize that $\phi$ is not a ring homomorphism. It is only compatible with multiplication, i.e. $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. As a counter-example take $R = S = K[X]$ a polynomial ring over a field $K$ and let $\phi$ be the algebra homomorphism given by $\phi(X) = X^2$.

Comment: Does the statement hold if the map is surjective?

Comment: If one took $K[X^2]$ as $S$ (saving surjectivity) then it would be true. Still surjectivity is not necessary. For example: map every irreducible of $R$ to a fixed irreducible of $S$ (and have $S$ contain other irreducibles).

Comment: Isn't $X^2$ an irreducible of $K[X^2]$?

Comment: That's the point :)

Comment: Aw. I kinda misinterpreted what you meant. Never mind.